# Xcode: How to go about making an editable list of locations to set/see on a Map View

Tags: xcode

Not sure how to ask this. In a nutshell, I'm an Xcode noob. I have a map view which I can search for an address and then get the coordinates for - that much is fine.

My question is: I want to present the user with a "list" (is this a table or collection view?) of 1 to 8 locations (user can add/delete at will) that they can either select and view their selected location on the map view or select a new/blank location cell and then be presented with a map view ready to search and store an address.

Like I said, the search and store is fine, but I need to pointed in the right direction of:
- what storyboard object to use
- how to add/delete 1 to 8 cells/fields/whatever they are called
- how to reuse the map view

I know this is vague question with potentially a lot of steps and code, so I'm not searching for a pre-written example, I'm more after the tools and method to use.

Any help/direction would be awesome :)

Comment: The list of cells will be a `UITableView`, vertically scrollable editable list. The objects on the map will be MKAnnotations, they have coordinates and are selectable. The mapview object will be MKMapView, you can just drag it into its place in storyboard (Interface Builder) and based on user selection you will just adjust its view area. So things to search/study are `UITableView` (datasource and delegate methods), `MKMapView` and `MKAnnotation` protocol / `MKAnnotationView` class.

Comment: Thanks. Why is this a comment? I want to select it as my answer :)

Comment: There you go :). Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of cells will be a UITableView, vertically scrollable editable list. The objects on the map will be MKAnnotations, they have coordinates and are selectable. The mapview object will be MKMapView, you can just drag it into its place in storyboard (Interface Builder) and based on user selection you will just adjust its view area. So things to search/study are UITableView (datasource and delegate methods), MKMapView and MKAnnotation protocol / MKAnnotationView class.